# Email storage server - NAS or SAN?

Tags: networking, email, storage, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

I'm looking for storage server that could store ~34TB (34 SSD disks of 1TB) of emails. I'm thinking about two NAS QNAP storage servers, but I'm not sure if it's OK to use NAS instead of SAN. Any help?

Comment: Why would you just ignore the text we put right in front of you when you sign up for this site stating what we do cover here and what we don't (this included recommendations, as they change over time)?

Comment: I didn't sign up, just wrote anonymously :P

Comment: Even so in the middle of the front page it says "Our community is defined by a specific set of topics in the help center; please stick to those topics" with a link to the help center.

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely dependent on the software you are using.  Exchange, for example, does not support NAS protocols such as NFS or CIFS/SMB for its databases; only SAN and DAS solutions like iSCSI or Fibre Channel.

There is also general confusion about what constitutes NAS and SAN.  Many new products are what is called "unified storage"; a combination of NAS and SAN protocols.  If you are accessing the storage system as a block-level device (FC, iSCSI, etc), then you are using it as a SAN.  If you are accessing it at the file level (NFS, CIFS, etc), then you are using it as a NAS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm thinking about buying two QNAP TS-EC2480U-RP 24-Bay servers, 36 SSD and 2 HDD and use RAID 10. Is it effective to use NAS for storing emails?

Comment: @ServerGeek4000: Product recomendations are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm not looking for recommendation. I just want to know which network is more useful in my case. SAN or NAS. If there is no difference, then I'm choosing NAS and leave you all alone in peace!

Comment: "`This is entirely dependent on the software you are using`"

Comment: Exchange's recommendation is to use local disks, non-SSD, as this is the cheapest option, and then do a DAG with multiple servers. But if you want to store 34 TB of e-mail (looks like a bigger environment), it looks like you're way over your head, and I suggest to use a consultant with experience in this.

Comment: What mail server should I use for SSD disks? I need to calculate IOPS.

Comment: @ServerGeek4000: It's complete nonsense to ask what kind of server to use with SSD disks. You start designing your solution on the completely wrong end. Honestly, do yourself a favor and either use a commercial mail provider or hire a consultant who has actual experience in designing such a system.